# Plan to visit places in Hiroshima

Tags: japan, planning, tokyo

I am travelling from Tokyo to Hiroshima via Nozomi early morning Saturday and reaching Hiroshima at 9;15 AM and my return from Hiroshima the next day evening 6Pm. So i have about 2 days and a night stay to visit places in Hiroshima.

My plan is to cover Hiroshima city and Miyajima.

**Day1: Miyajima (start from Hiroshima station at 9:15Am )**

> Itsukushima Shrine
>
> Mount Misen
>
> Daisho-in Temple
>
> Senjokaku
>
> Walking Trails
>
> Museum of History
>
> Miyajima Aquarium

**Day2:Hiroshima city(Start as early as possible from Hiroshima station )**

> Peace Park
>
> Mazda Museum
>
> Hiroshima Downtown
>
> Hiroshima Castle

Is it okay to cover all the places in Miyajima in one day and is one day too much to visit places mentioned in Day 2. I would be more than happy to alter my schedule to utilize time perfectly. Also is it possible to fit in a visit to any of Onomichi, Iwakuni, Tomonoura,Okunoshima  ?

Comment: This is a spectacular itinerary!  On the other hand, opinions will vary as to "...is it okay to cover all the places...or is it too much..."  We don't know the answer, nobody does. It's essentially an opinion poll and we can't participate in those.  Please read the FAQ.  Close voting as opinion-based, sorry

Comment: I aint asking bluntly like is it possible to cover Hiroshima in two days. I have done my homework to arrive at a plan and asking is it possible to cover a Few places in certain timeframe.! Anyways as the community decides

Comment: I found that one day in Miyajima is plenty, as it's quite small. However, I didn't climb up Mount Misen or go to the Aquarium, so it might be different for you.

Comment: While some people vary in how quickly they travel or how quickly they see an attraction, it's practical to give an approximate guide on whether an itinerary is feasible or not. And it's important to check, because many travellers try to cram in too much into too short a period of time.

Comment: thanks @drat  I did climb up Mount Misen. it took around 6-7 hours at Miyajima. I didnt go to Aquariam either. I was able to cover Hiroshima Day 2 plan in about 6 hours. All in all a good trip